# Is there an OSI PI adapter or connector to Apache Spark?

Tags: interface, apache-spark, streaming, connector

How can i get data from OSI PI into Apache Spark? specially in the case where data is streaming? if there is no direct adapter, what's the alternatives to get the data in osi pi into spark?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OSI PI JDBC](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Products/Developer-Technologies/PI-JDBC-Driver/Overview) driver, and pump data into Apache Kafka. Spark has good integration with Kafka.

[Kafka Integration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html)